# How to update the database trigger by time using codeIgniter?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

For example, I have a table with 3 fields:

```
id, status, datetime
```

If the status is 0, when the datetime is arrive, the status will become 1.
How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CodeIgniter to do this, create a model, then a function, which will do the following:

```
public function updateDateTime($id)
{
    $this->db->set('status', '1');
    $this->db->set('datetime', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', TRUE);
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('table');
}
```

Reference: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#insert

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$this->db->set('datetime', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', FALSE);`? according to documentation: `set() will also accept an optional third parameter ($escape), that will prevent data from being escaped if set to FALSE.`